# How can I protect my website content from being accessed by cURL?

Tags: php, security, curl

I have a website that requires users to log in before accessing the content. On each protected page, I use this code, which works fine when accessed from a browser:

```
// check if they are logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])) {
    header('Location: ./login.php');
}

// functions to display the page
display_page();
```

The problem is that if I access the page using cURL, the redirect doesn't happen and the content is returned. This concerns me... what can I do?

I tried adding else if(isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])){//display page} but that didn't work.

Comment: put an `exit()` after your header() call, so that your page never gets sent to the unauthorized person in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In its present state you send a header to redirect the user to the loginpage, but you still serve up the page content.  Just stop doing that, like this:

```
// check if they are logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])) {
    header('Location: ./login.php');
    // and get out of here if they aren't
    exit();
}
// OK, they're logged in, let them see some content
// functions to display the page
display_page();
```

or

```
// check if they are logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])) {
    header('Location: ./login.php');
    // and get out of here if they aren't
} else {
   // OK, they're logged in, let them see some content
   // functions to display the page
   display_page();
}
```

Comment: If you tried them and they didn't work, then you didn't try them correctly: PHP will exit on an exit, nor will it run both parts of an `if`

Comment: You're right, I forgot to restart the server like a dummy. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Protecting your website from being accessed by curl is, to my knowledge, not possible. curl can come up with any kind of faked browser identification. Aside from that, no server can safely know if the requests are not coming from a browser.

If you, however, want curl to react to the headers, try this:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

From the docs:

> TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part
>   of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many
>   "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is
>   set).

[See the PHP doc for further details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: You're assuming that he has control over how people use curl to read his content...

Comment: -1 for saying its not possible. It's very possible. Otherwise, every website would easily be hacked.

Comment: Ok then, i would like to learn how its done please. Enlighten me!

Comment: @CharlieMartin: That's a specious claim; if it were true every website would be just as easily hacked through a web browser. On the other hand, setting options to PHP's own built-in cURL has absolutely nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: @fvu - not quite. But if you read his question it says: *The problem is that if I access the page using cURL, [...]*. I therefore assumed the information might be useful for him.

Comment: The way to do it is just like @fvu's answer. You kill the request execution if the session does not exist. Curl does not follow redirect headers. Browsers follow redirect headers. If you send a redirect header, but still serve the content then anyone using curl still gets the protected content. If you kill the script, they don't.

Comment: Sorry, Charlie Martin, but this still does not even peripherally explain how you would go about the task of safely distinguishing between a browser's and a curl request. You cannot safely do so. You say curl doesn't follow headers, which is not true, because it can be configured to do so. Therefore you cannot safely take the route you just proposed.

Comment: I think I was misunderstanding you. You meant preventing people from being able to send a curl request to your website is impossible. I took it as preventing people from accessing your secure content with curl is impossible. Clarify that and I will +1 you back up (I can't change my vote unless you edit your answer).

Comment: @squarecat I understand you, I extrapolated that statement to the fact that anybody using curl being able to access the data is an issue - the info on how to teach curl good manners in this matter is useful anyways.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, but I'll stick to the downvote because in my opinion my choice of words perfectly reflects what i wanted to say. *Protecting your website from being accessed by curl* ... nowhere am i talking about secure content, neither would it make any sense in that context.